# Office 365 API on premise integration

Tags: api, office365, localserver

We are making a school dashboard for student to see an overview of what is happening in all the available systems at the school. We want to make Office 365 notifications. We know that this is not a problem with the O365 online API. However, teachers make use of O365 on premise. Is it possible to call an API on this local server and what do the system admins needs to do to make this work? Or, is this in the end, working through he cloud server of O365?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office 365 Service Comms APIs are for the cloud offering only. For on premise health, the easiest way is to use PowerShell.